# Attempting to run a query and set the count to a low number

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL syntax problem.

Query below will run but result is:

> ERROR:  out of memory for query result

```
SELECT
AD.ADDRESS_DETAIL_PID as ADDRESS_DETAIL_PID,
AD.STREET_LOCALITY_PID as STREET_LOCALITY_PID,
AD.LOCALITY_PID as LOCALITY_PID,
AD.BUILDING_NAME as BUILDING_NAME
```

When  the query is amended to:

```
set FETCH_COUNT=1000
SELECT
AD.ADDRESS_DETAIL_PID as ADDRESS_DETAIL_PID,
AD.STREET_LOCALITY_PID as STREET_LOCALITY_PID,
AD.LOCALITY_PID as LOCALITY_PID,
AD.BUILDING_NAME as BUILDING_NAME
```

the result is:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 3: SELECT
>           ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 23

except that when a colon ; is included at the end the rssult is:

> ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "fetch_count" SQL state:
>   42704

I am seeking help with the syntax.

Comment: you forgot a `;` after the `set fetch_count` statement.

Comment: except that when a colon ; is included at the end the rssult is:

Comment: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "fetch_count"
SQL state: 42704

Answer (score 0):

`FETCH_COUNT` is a `psql` interval variable and is not executed on the server.

`SET` is a SQL command that's executed on the server and cannot be used for setting `psql` internal variables. use `\set` instead.

```
\set FETCH_COUNT 1000
```

Comment: amended line provides this result:

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 75: \set FETCH_COUNT 1000;
         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 2278

Comment: @gregT : Aren't you using `psql`?

Comment: PostgreSQL 10.4 under pgAdmin 4

Comment: @gregT : As I said `FETCH_COUNT` is a psql variable and `\set` is a psql meta command, it cannot work in pgAdmin

Comment: Thanks for this.  Is there a solution to limit the count?

Comment: I rewrote the query and it now works - thanks for your help kaushik-nayak